# Ag-Grid tries to load all items at once with partial store type

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Here are my grid options:
`public gridOptions = <GridOptions>{  columnDefs: [ { field: 'templateID' }, ], debug: true, defaultColDef: { flex: 1, minWidth: 100, resizable: true, }, rowModelType: 'serverSide', cacheBlockSize: this.pagingCount, serverSideStoreType: 'partial', onGridReady: (params) => { this.gridApi0 = params.api; this.gridApi0.sizeColumnsToFit(); this.gridApi0.setDomLayout('autoHeight'); }, };`
for some reason ag grid tries to load all the items as soon as it loads, even though the grid is not scrolled and serverSideStoreType is set to partial.
what might be a problem? how to configure serverside pagination properly?

I tried to both specify rowCount to total number of items and omit the property. no effect